# how to find footer's value of gridview on RowCommand event?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I want to find footer's value on the event of `RowCommand` in `vb.net`??

I'm assigning footer's value run-time on `RowCreated`.

```
e.Row.Cells(2).Text = FOOTERVALUE
e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "Total Subjects"
```

And this footer is for Parent Grid. I'm using nested gridview.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Protected Sub Gridview1RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowCommand   
     Dim Lblcolval = CType(dgrd_WWWH.FooterRow.FindControl("yourcolumn") ,Label)
 End Sub

Protected Sub Gridview1_How_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gridview1.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType And DataControlRowType.Footer Or (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then
  Dim ddlresp As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ddlResp"), DropDownList)
  SrchWhoBind(ddlresp)
  ddlresp.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(Session("Uname"))
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, just needed to write the code in `rowDataBound` instead of `rowCreated`.